# What is the smallest ExtJS package?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Does anyone know the bare minimum files required for Ext JS 2.2? I know the ExtJS site has a feature to ["build"](http://extjs.com/products/extjs/build/) a small version of ExtJS (ext.js) as a replacement for ext-all.js but that's for minimizing the size of ExtJS on the client. I'm interested in minimizing what's on the server. Currently the SDK comes with the following subdirectories:

### ext-2.2/

```
adapter
air
build
docs
examples
resources
source
```

I think its pretty safe to remove examples, docs, and air. However, are there other things we can remove to make this smaller or is there a resource (besides the large javascript source code corpus) that documents the minimum required files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This link explains the include order
[What is the proper include order for my JavaScript files?](http://extjs.com/learn/Ext_Getting_Started#What_is_the_proper_include_order_for_my_JavaScript_files.3F)

This is the minimum include set

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../extjs/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
```

The ext-all.css depends on files in ../extjs/resources/css so you should include that entire directory structure also.

So you'd need the following files at a minimum

- extjs/resources/**/*
- extjs/adapter/ext/ext-base.js
- extjs/ext-all.js

If you're not using Ext JS for any of the UI components then you don't need any of the stylesheets and supporting images, but in that case you'd have to question why you're using Ext JS since that's it's strong point.

Comment: Why Two files of js ? what are their roles ?

Answer (score 1):

Ext Core
http://extjs.com/products/extcore/