# How to minimize Ext JS / Ext Gantt folder for production?

Tags: extjs

I just finished development of a Gantt chart page inside our .NET (WebForms) project using Ext JS and Ext Gantt technology. Works great as I described in a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085614/gantt-chart-in-javascript-jquery-extjs/9232475#9232475).

My problem now is that my folder container Ext JS and Ext Gantt even after removing obvious overhead is huge compared to the rest of hte project and my team is complaining. So I need to reduce this folder as much as I can just leaving there "exactly" (in a reasonable way) what I need to run the Gantt chart and nothing else for now.

I did try for a couple of hours but still cannot find a good / easy recipe.
The following links talk about this but I am still confused:

1. http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?84560-include-only-required-extjs-files
2. [What is the smallest ExtJS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214348/what-is-the-smallest-extjs-package)
3. http://www.sencha.com/products/extcore/
4. [What do you use to minimize and compress JavaScript libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599911/what-do-you-use-to-minimize-and-compress-javascript-libraries)

Anybody with experience doing this?. I know Ext JS has a tool called builder but I never used it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tools you are looking for are the Sencha SDK suite. The JS Builder is what you need
http://www.sencha.com/products/sdk-tools/

Unfortunately, I have not yet worked with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a jsb3 file for your Gannt application like follows,

```
sencha create jsb -a index.html -p gantt.jsb3
```

hope your running this command from the EXT Gannt folder.then you will get a file name gantt.jsb3.you can build that file to obtain a production build for gantt app, as follows,

```
sencha build -p gantt.jsb3 -d .
```

For more info please refer,

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/getting_started

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, they've moved to the "Sencha Cmd" tool: http://www.sencha.com/blog/all-new-sencha-cmd/